# How to use a typescript generic class constructor as a parameter in a function call

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to use the following API from the package `typescript-json-serializer`.

```js
export declare function deserialize<T>(json: object, type: new (...params: Array<any>) => T): T;
```

A simple working sample code for this API usage is:

```js
const result: MyClass = deserialize<MyClass>(json, MyClass);
```

My usage is a little more tricky. Instead of `MyClass`, I would like to have a generic class, something like `MyClass<T>`.

I tried the following, but it is failing to compile

```js
const result: MyClass<T> = deserialize<MyClass<T>>(json, MyClass<T>);
```

The mentioned error is
`Value of type 'typeof MyClass' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?`

Any idea how to solve this ?

Updates :
In my last exemple, T is a real class.

```js
const result: MyClass<MyClass2> = deserialize<MyClass<MyClass2>>(json, MyClass<MyClass2>);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want `result` to be.  An instance of `MyClass<T>` *for which `T`*?  You could possibly want `const result: MyClass<any> = ...`, but saying `T` when there is no type `T` defined is not allowed.  It helps to provide a [mcve] where you give a toy implementation of `MyClass` and what you expect to deserialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic parameter of the constructor is implied by the T annotation on `deserialize`. The correct and typesafe syntax is:

```
deserialize<MyClass<T>>(json, MyClass);
```

Comment: Is there a type named `T` in scope here?  It's hard to tell from the original question.

Comment: I assumed it was just paraphrasing a type bound outside somewhere, e.g. this is in a generic class's method. If it's intended to be a generic T by itself, the issue is about generic const which it's entirely different than the syntax problem of the question.

Comment: Il sorry for thé misunderstanding. I have added an update explaining that T really exist. What I mean is I need `const result: MyClass<MyClass2> = deserialize<MyClass<MyClass2>>(json, MyClass<MyClass2>);`

Comment: @Omar BELKHODJA My answer still holds, just substitute T for MyClass2.

Comment: The compiling is ok, but the result is not. Inside MyClass, MyClass2, should be used to deserialize one property if type MyClass2. Instead, that property is deserialized to Object.

Comment: I talked with the developer of `typescript-json-serializer` and he told me that generic are not supported. So I believe @concat your answer is correct, and the bad result, is because an unsupported feature.